# my C# program is freezing when trying to decrypt my own cipher

Tags: c#, algorithm, encryption, matrix, mono

So I have built my own (toy) encryption algorithm using matrices. The program is supposed to encrypt the plaintext with the key and then ask you the key and print out the decrypted plaintext. Everything is ok until the point when the C# program generates the 'key matrix' from the key to decrypt the cipher. Note that the first time that it generates the 'key matrix' from the key it is ok but the second time it freezes. Here is the code.

```
using System;

namespace MatrixEncryption
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a relatively short piece of text:");
            string txt = Console.ReadLine();
            txt += "L";
            Console.WriteLine("Enter an encryption key:");
            string ekey = Console.ReadLine();
            int times = 0;
            while(true)
            {
                if(txt.Length + 1 < (Math.Pow((double)ekey.Length,(double)times))) break;
                times++;
            }
            times++;
            Console.WriteLine(times);
            Matrix keym = new Matrix(ekey.Length^times, ekey.Length^times);
            string res = ekey;
            for(int i = 0; i<times - 1; i++)
            {
                res = GetCharRep(GenMatrix(res));
            }
            keym = GenMatrix(res);
            Console.WriteLine(keym.cols + ":" + keym.rows);
            Matrix passm = new Matrix(keym.rows, keym.cols);
            int unicnt = 0;
            Random a = new Random();
            for(int i = 0; i<(keym.rows); i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j<(keym.cols); j++)
                {
                    if(unicnt == 0)
                    {
                        passm[i, j] = (byte)txt.Length;
                        unicnt++;
                        continue;
                    }
                    if(unicnt < txt.Length)
                    {
                        passm[i, j] = (byte)txt[unicnt - 1];  
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int aa = a.Next();
                        passm[i, j] = (byte)(aa % byte.MaxValue);
                    }
                    unicnt++;
                }
            }
            Matrix cipherm = new Matrix(keym.rows, keym.cols);
            Matrix TwoMatrix = new Matrix(cipherm.rows, cipherm.cols);
            for(int i = 0; i<TwoMatrix.rows; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j<TwoMatrix.cols; j++)
                {
                    TwoMatrix[i, j] = 2;
                }
            }
            cipherm = NotMul(passm + TwoMatrix, keym + TwoMatrix);
            Console.WriteLine("Enciphered text : " + GetCharRep(cipherm));
            Console.WriteLine("Enter key now to check if decryptable cipher : ");
            string keyy = Console.ReadLine();
            int timesx = cipherm.cols;
            double aaa = (double)timesx;
            double bbb = (double)keyy.Length;
            timesx = (int)Math.Log(aaa, bbb);
            Matrix keymx = new Matrix(timesx, timesx);
            string resss = keyy;
            for(int i = 0; i<timesx; i++)
            {
                resss = GetCharRep(GenMatrix(resss));
            }
            keymx = GenMatrix(resss);
            if(keymx != keym)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("STUPID COMPUTER xD");
                Console.WriteLine(cipherm.cols.ToString() + ":" + cipherm.rows.ToString());
            }
            Matrix ress = new Matrix(keymx.rows, keymx.cols);
            keymx = keymx + TwoMatrix;
            ress = NotDiv(cipherm, keymx);
            ress = ress - TwoMatrix;
            Console.WriteLine(GetCharRep(ress).Substring(0, (int)(ress[0, 0])));
        }
        public static Matrix NotMul(Matrix m1, Matrix m2)
        {
            Matrix result = Matrix.ZeroMatrix(m1.cols, m1.rows);
            for(int i = 0; i<m1.rows; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j<m2.cols; j++)
                {
                    result[i, j] = (m1[i, j] * m2[i, j]);
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
        public static Matrix NotDiv(Matrix m1, Matrix m2)
        {
                        Matrix result = Matrix.ZeroMatrix(m1.cols, m1.rows);
            for(int i = 0; i<m1.rows; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j<m2.cols; j++)
                {
                    result[i, j] = m1[i, j] * (1/m2[i, j]);
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
        public static Matrix GenMatrix(string key)
        {
            Matrix ret = new Matrix(key.Length, key.Length);
            for(int i = 0; i<key.Length; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j<key.Length; j++)
                {
                    ret[i, j] = (byte)(Math.Pow((double)key[i], (double)key[j]) % byte.MaxValue);
                }
            }
            return ret;
        }
        public static string GetCharRep(Matrix INM)
        {
            string ret = "";
            for(int i = 0; i<INM.rows; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j<INM.cols; j++)
                {
                    ret += (char)((byte)INM[i, j] % byte.MaxValue);
                }
            }
            return ret;
        }
    }
}
```

For a little bit of explanation: 
1. The matrix class is burrowed from the internet and is too large to be put here.
2. Explaining the encryption algorithm:

Shortly all that happens is that the code generates two matrices, one from the plaintext and one from the key (you can guess how exactly it is generated by the code). 
Then it multiplies each element of the key and the plaintext (NOT MATRIX MULITIPLICATION JUST EACH ELEMENT) the algorithm also involves random numbers e.t.c. But the problem I believe here is that the process of turning the key into the 'key matrix' is not repeated correctly the second time. Anyway I don't know a good solution so please help.

Comment: just a comment - it worked before I tweaked the algorithm a little bit

Comment: If you had a very similar version  that worked, then the simplest troubleshooting approach is probably to compare the working version to the new "tweaked" version. For example, you could add the "tweaks" one at a time until it breaks, and then step into that part of the code. Save a separate copy of your current code, and then use CTRL-Z to get back to what you had working before for comparison. The information you have given here is not sufficient for us to divine the answer.

Comment: I was afraid if I gave all the information it could take too much to fit here xD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I solved the first part, It isn't freezing any more I just changed the

```
    for(int i = 0; i<times - 1; i++)
    {
        res = GetCharRep(GenMatrix(res));
    }
```

to

```
    for(int i = 0; i<times - 2; i++)
    {
        res = GetCharRep(GenMatrix(res));
    }
```

But this time the dimensions of the `ress` matrix and the `TwoMatrix` Matrix don't match.

Comment: It's better to ask than assume sometimes: Do you know about breakpoints, debug mode, and stepping through the code line by line in Visual Studio? If not, a quick search of these terms in Google should find you a detailed explanation or tutorial.

Comment: My questions seem to always get unanswered D: almost never anybody really ever looks at them. D:D:D:D:D: )-:

Comment: This is not really a question, it is a request to debug your application. That's off topic here. You would be better off trying to learn to use a debugger, stepping through this application would certainly have helped you. Furthermore, you answered your own question within a day. Stackoverflow is slightly less suited for questions needing a direct answer (although it works for some topics); better to test yourself some more in such a short time frame and post when you *really* get stuck.